# Titanium Alloy : How to pass several onClick events?

Tags: titanium-alloy

The following code :

```
    <TableView id="tableview2" onClick="rowWasClicked ; goEdit" >
```

get me the following error message :

```
The event listener rowWasClicked ; goEdit is not defined.
```

More importantly, the function goEdit is never fired.

How to get both functions fired ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want fired two onClick's events, a possible trick is:

```
<TableView id="tableview2" onClick="rowWasClicked" onClick="goEdit" >
```

With this code you can fire two onClick's events at the same time.